# Parameterization of the curve of intersection of a surface

Tags: calculus

I need to parameterize the curve of intersection of the surface:

$x^2+y+z=2$ and $xy+z=1$

What I've done so far is said:

$z=2-x^{2}-y$ therefore $xy+(2-x^{2}-y)=1$ (using substitution). Then, we get $x^{2}-xy+y=1$.

This is where I'm stuck, this cannot be factored any further and so I can't finish the parameterization. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You can solve the quadratic, can you not?

Comment: I don't see how this x^2-xy+y=1 can be solved using the quadratic equation?

Comment: Maybe even a linear wrt $y$: $y(1-x)=1-x^2$, hence $x=1$ or $y=x+1$ @user3472798

Comment: Upon solving the quadratic equation $x^2-yx+y-1$, we see that $x=y-1$ or $x=1$.  Can you parameterize now?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get *one* parametrization however you can get two:

The intersection of $x^2+y+z=2$ and $xy+z=1$ consists of the union of a line: $(1,t,1-t)$ and a parabola: $(s-1,s,-s^2+s+1)$ which intersect in the point $(1,2,-1)$. Maple:

```
> solve([x^2+y+z = 2, x*y+z = 1]);
                             /                        2        \ 
{x = 1, y = y, z = -y + 1}, { x = y - 1, y = y, z = -y  + y + 1 }
                             \                                 / 

with(plots); 
p1 := plot3d([1, y, -y+1], x = -10 .. 10, y = -10 .. 10);
p2 := plot3d([y-1, y, -y^2+y+1], x = -10 .. 10, y = -10 .. 10);
display(p1, p2); #manually rotated to get the image
```

[image: line union parabola]